# Replace special characters in specific field

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression, cut

how to replace special character in specific field?

**INPUT**

`xxxx,11/2019,xxx`

**OUTPUT**

`xxxx,11,2019,xxx`

As you see that am looking to replace `/` with `,` in `$2` only.

How achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/\//,",",$2); print}'
```

This uses `awk`'s `gsub()` function to do a global regexp search and replace on field 2.

If you want to replace only the first occurence of `/` in $2, use `sub()` rather than `gsub()`.

NOTE: the default output field separator `OFS` is a space.  You need to set it to `,` (same as the input field separator `FS`), otherwise the `print` will output all the fields with spaces separating them.

From the man page for GNU `awk`:

> **gsub(r, s [, t])**
>
> For each substring matching the regular expression `r` in the string
>   `t`, substitute the string `s`, and return the number of substitutions.
>
> If `t` is not supplied, use $0.
>
> An `&` in the replacement text is replaced with the text that was
>   actually matched.
>
> Use `\&` to get a literal &. (This must be typed as `\\&`; see [GAWK:
>   Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) for a fuller discussion of the rules for
>   &'s and backslashes in the replacement text of `sub()`, `gsub()`, and
>   `gensub()`.)

Answer (score -1):

The command given in [the previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412781/45383) can be much simpler. Tested and working fine.

Since changes need to be done in second column, I have added the same content in a second column and tested.

```
echo "echo "xxxx,11/2019,xxx xxxx,11/2019,xxx" " |
awk '{print gsub("/",",",$2);print $0}'
```

Output:

```
xxxx,11/2019,xxx xxxx,11,2019,xxx
```